# SQL Server Foreign key: if we want to merge multiple values

Tags: sql-server

Good day,

Let's say we have a parent table whose columns are:

```
[1] id, int, Identity, Primary
[2] name, nvarchar, unique
```

And a child table:

```
[1] parent, nvarchar, FK reference [parent].[name], ON UPDATE CASACADE
[2..] other columns
```

What if we now have several entries in parent table, for example,

```
| id | name  |
| 0  | test1 |
| 1  | test2 |
| 2  | test3 |
```

and all of them have referenced rows in [child] table.
If we want to "Merge" test1 to test3.. (i.e. no more test1 and all rows referenced to test1 should become test3), but the [parent].[name] is unique... Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't get it.  Show the results that you want to achieve.  And clarify whether you want these as updates to a table or as the results from a query.

Comment: why do you refer to parent in child table as nvarchar? Better to link children to parents by the parent ID column which is INT. Also, the best practice is to always specify length of the nvarchar columns, e.g. nvarchar(30).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you've chosen to use `name` as the foreign key, doing that forfeits the benefits of having the `id` on the parent table.

If I understand correctly: what you want to do is move all of the child rows that reference `'test1'` to `'test3'` and get rid of `'test1'` all together.

For this example I'm using `c` as `[2]` and `p` as `[1]`:

```
update c set parent='test3' where parent = 'test1';
delete from p where name='test1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the respondents above make reference to your PK/FK relationship, and I strongly agree. It is always best practice to make your ID column in the primary table the PK, and set the FK equal to the PK ID value.

Your primary table looks fine, it is the FK reference that has an issue. I would change the child table (as provided in question) to:

```
[1] parentid, int, FK reference [parent].[id], ON UPDATE CASACADE
```

The answer to the primary question is updating your foreign table to reference the new PK, which has nothing to do with the cascade option, but it will change the PK unique name associated with the foreign table rows. After making the Foreign key change, you could then run the following two t-sql statements.

```
UPDATE Child
SET parentid = 2
WHERE parented = 0

DELETE
FROM Parent
WHERE ID = 0
```